# axis on top not respected on addplot3

Tags: pgfplots, axis

Despite using `axis on top=false` the grid is overlayed on the graph of `addplot3`. I applied the same on a simpler graph which is using `addplot` and I've got the expected behavior of the grid behind the graph.
Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.colormaps}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}


  \begin{axis}[
      domain=-1:1,
      xmin=-1.2, xmax=1.2,
      colormap/copper,
      grid=major,
      axis on top=false,
      ymin=-1.2, ymax=1.2, zmin=0,
      view={0}{90},
      colorbar horizontal,
      colorbar style={point meta min=0,point meta max=0.7},
      colorbar/width=2.5mm,
      grid=major,
    ]

    \addplot3[
      samples=50,
      contour gnuplot={
        output point meta=rawz,
        levels={0.2,0.4,0.6},
        labels=true,
        handler/.style=smooth,
      },
      z filter/.code=\def\pgfmathresult{0},
    ] gnuplot {
      min(a,b) = (a < b) ? a : b
      r2(x,y) = min(1,(x^2+y^2))
      (x,y,6*(1-r2(x,y))*(27-8*r2(x,y)) / (73 * pi) )
    };
  \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! I guess you need to set the samples to `25`, and your problem can be solved by using `set layers` and drawing the contours on the `axis foreground` layer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.colormaps}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}


  \begin{axis}[set layers,
      domain=-1:1,
      xmin=-1.2, xmax=1.2,
      colormap/copper,
      grid=major,
      axis on top=false,
      ymin=-1.2, ymax=1.2, zmin=0,
      view={0}{90},
      colorbar horizontal,
      colorbar style={point meta min=0,point meta max=0.7},
      colorbar/width=2.5mm,
      grid=major,
    ]

    \addplot3[on layer=axis foreground,
      samples=25,
      contour gnuplot={
        output point meta=rawz,
        levels={0.2,0.4,0.6},
        labels=true,
        handler/.style=smooth,
      },
      z filter/.code=\def\pgfmathresult{0},
    ] gnuplot {
      min(a,b) = (a < b) ? a : b
      r2(x,y) = min(1,(x^2+y^2))
      (x,y,6*(1-r2(x,y))*(27-8*r2(x,y)) / (73 * pi) )
    };
  \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps I should have post the whole code, in my original code the graph is part of `groupplot` and I think it is not possible to use `set layers` in `groupplot` (well I tried any way but it entirely removed the grid and shifted the graph)

Comment: @user3074069 I'm not sure but [layers seem to work with groupplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/305122/121799). You may just have to set them explicitly. It is also a bit unfortunate that you tell me afterwards because my answer *does* work for the question you post. How would anyone be able to answer your question if you do not provide the full information?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I followed their advice and also added `cell picture=true` to your solution when using `groupplot`, and everything is working as desired.

Comment: Well nearly, the `colorbar` is not placed correctly :(

Comment: @user3074069 You may want to post a minimal group plot example that shows this, otherwise it might be hard to solve this. Note also that I will be offline now, so I'd suggest that you ask a new question, which will be on the top of the list, so get more attention. Asking questions is free, so you don't lose anything. ;-)