# Pgfplots contour / axis on top = false

Tags: pgfplots, contour

In spite of `axis on top = false` option, the 0 contour line in the following MWE, which is the x=0 equation line, doesn't appear.
Any solution ?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=center, axis on top=false, domain=-2:2, y domain=-1.5:1.5,
            view = {0}{90}, colorbar]
        \addplot3[contour gnuplot={labels=false,
                levels={-0.2, -0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.2}},
                samples=100]{x*exp(-x^2-y^2))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/450780/263192, `set layers` and `on layer=axis foreground` solves this.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=center,
        set layers,
        domain=-2:2,
        y domain=-1.5:1.5,
        view = {0}{90},
        colorbar
    ]
    \addplot3[
        on layer=axis foreground,
        contour gnuplot={
            labels=false,
            levels={-0.2, -0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.2}
        },
        samples=100
    ] {x*exp(-x^2-y^2))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]