# axis on top=false with addplot3 and groupplot, failed placement of colorbar

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots, axis

The goal is to have the grid below the graph, the `axis on top=false` is working for `addplot` but not for `addplot3`, to fix that I applied the solution proposed in [axis on top not respected on addplot3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450779/axis-on-top-not-respected-on-addplot3) , but as I'm using `groupplots` the `set layers` alone is badly affecting the layout. I also applied [pgfplot legend on top of grid but below graphs in axis as well as groupplot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255669/pgfplot-legend-on-top-of-grid-but-below-graphs-in-axis-as-well-as-groupplot/305122) (adding `cell picture=true`) which improved things, but I still got the `colorbar` missplaced and without legend.

First picture is the wanted graph layout, **but it will need to have the grid behind**. (it's obtain by commenting the code marked with: %% Added to "fix" ...)
[image]

Second picture is the result I managed to get so far (with the code in this post), grid is now behind the graph, but the layout got screwed up.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.colormaps}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{groupplot}[
      set layers, cell picture=true,  %% Added to "fix" axis on top=false
      domain=-1:1,
      xmin=-1.2, xmax=1.2,
      colormap/copper,
      group style={group size=1 by 2, horizontal sep=0pt,vertical sep=0pt},
      grid=major,
      ylabel absolute,
      axis on top=false,
    ]

    \nextgroupplot[
        axis equal image=true,
        ymin=0, ymax=0.8,
        xticklabel=\empty,
        ylabel={Probability},
      ]

    \addplot[
        mesh,
        samples=25,
      ] gnuplot {
        min(a,b) = (a < b) ? a : b
        r2(x) = min(1,(x^2))
        6*(1-r2(x))*(27-8*r2(x)) / (73 * pi)
      };

    \node[above right] at (0,0) { $ y = 0 $ };

    \nextgroupplot[
      ymin=-1.2, ymax=1.2, zmin=0,
      view={0}{90},
      colorbar horizontal,
      colorbar style={point meta min=0,point meta max=0.7},
      colorbar/width=2.5mm,
      grid=major,
      clip=false,
      ylabel={$y$},
      xlabel={$x$},
    ]

    \addplot3[
      on layer=axis foreground, %% Added to "fix" axis on top=false
      samples=25,
      contour gnuplot={
        output point meta=rawz,
        levels={0.2,0.4,0.6},
        labels=true,
        handler/.style=smooth,
      },
      z filter/.code=\def\pgfmathresult{0},
    ] gnuplot {
      min(a,b) = (a < b) ? a : b
      r2(x,y) = min(1,(x^2+y^2))
      (x,y,6*(1-r2(x,y))*(27-8*r2(x,y)) / (73 * pi) )
    };

    \coordinate[label=below right:{\tiny P1}] (P1) at (-0.65, -0.3, 0);
    \coordinate[label=below right:{\tiny P2}] (P2) at (axis cs: 0.3,  0.4, 0);
    \coordinate[label=above right:{\tiny O} ] (O)  at (axis cs: 0.0,  0.0, 0.0);

    \fill[black] (O) circle (1pt);
    \fill[black] (P1) circle (2pt);
    \fill[black] (P2) circle (2pt);
    \draw (0,0) circle(1);

    \draw[<->,shorten >= 2pt, shorten <= 2pt] (0,0) -- (-55:1)
      node[midway,above,sloped] { \tiny $ r = 1 $ };

    \draw[->,shorten >= 4pt, shorten <= 4pt] (P1) -- (P2);
  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you perhaps explain precisely which output you want to get? I do reproduce your upper screen shot with your code, how does one obtain the lower one, and, more importantly, what do you want to fix or achieve?

Comment: I edited my post to be more explicit.
That's strange the posted code should give you the second picture, the first one being obtained by commenting the line marked with: %% Added to "fix" .
I want to obtain the first picture *but* with the grid below the graph.

Comment: yes, just wondering, if I should delete it?

Comment: Ok, fine by me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question has been solved in the comments: updating tikz and pgfplots solved the issue.